# Unexpected token export with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I've seen some other answers and GitHub issues that describe this, but I haven't been able to find a solution in my case. I'm getting the dreaded `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` when trying to run jest.

```
project/node_modules/@agm/core/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './directives';
```

The code where these tests are being run works okay. The error seems to be coming from within jest itself. It *seems* like jest is transforming the file, but I could be wrong.

My jest configuration is

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I've tried updating the `transformIgnorePatterns` to `"<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@agm)"` and `"node_modules/(?!@agm)"`, `"node_modules/(?!@agm/core)"`, but none of those seem to make any difference.

How can I get jest to properly handle the files imported from `@agm/core`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several changes that I needed to get this to work. This should fix the issue when using `@agm/core` for an Angular 6 app is being used with jest.

```
yarn add --dev babel-preset-env
```

You should already have `babel-jest`.

Then update your jest configuration:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@agm)"
]
```

You will also need to add a `.babelrc` to use if you don't have one:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-env"]
}
```

This may work for other libraries that need a babel transformation as-installed.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're experiencing this for

```
/node_modules/@nestjs/common/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^
```

the fix is to add

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^uuid$': require.resolve('uuid'),
}
```

to the jest configuration, e.g. to `jest.config.js`.

Thanks to contributors at https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/9930.

Answer (score -1):

i would like to add that for babel 7+ i guess, instead of .babelrc use **babel.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['babel-preset-env'],
}
```